# mongo db pull element out of an array

Tags: mongodb

I have a small mongo document which looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5aa441e898cc0b32a819be0c"
    },
    "details": {
        "Artist": "Cyndi Lauper",
        "Album": "She's So Unusual",
        "ReleaseYear": 1983
    },
    "SongID": 1,
    "SongTitle": "Girls Just Want To Have Fund"
}
```

I need to pull the Artist element out of the details array but keep the data in the overall document.  The resulting document needs to look like this:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5aa441e898cc0b32a819be0c"
    },
    "details": {
        "Album": "She's So Unusual",
        "ReleaseYear": 1983
    },
    "SongID": 1,
    "SongTitle": "Girls Just Want To Have Fund",
    "Artist": "Cyndi Lauper"
}
```

I'm new to mongo so I'm not to strong in this. The collection is called songs so am thinking I need to do something like this:

```
db.songs.updateOne({},{$set : {"Artist":$pull{"detail.Artist"}}})
```

Any help and/or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Jonathan

Comment: I dont think my question is a duplicate. The other examples show how to remove an element from the array but in doing so, they loose the data in the removed element.  I want to save the data.  I just want to pull the array element called Artist out of the array so it will no longer be referenced with dot notation.

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this in the MongoDB shell:

```
var doc={doc:{key42:"value"},somekey:"value"};
doc.key42=doc.doc.key42;
delete doc.doc.key42;
```

After that you can write

```
doc
```

and press enter.
The output shold be:

```
{doc:{},somekey:"value",key42:"value"};
```

Then you can save the doc:

```
db.collection.save(doc);
```